# TInkerpop GraphTraversal: hasNext never return when searching shorter path

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to get the shorter path between 2 verticles with ignoring some verticles. My request is made on a graph database OrientDB.

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Path> allPath = // execution of my request (Too complicated to put it here)
if (!allPath.hasNext()) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
else {
    // DO SOME THINGS
}
```

My code executes my query, and I want to parse the result of my request. But, the code stay stuck in the `hasNext`.

Here is an example of my request executed:

```
g.V(1).repeat(bothE("knows").bothV().not(hasId(2,4,6)).simplePath()).until(hasId(5)).path();
```

I suppose that the problem come from the query made but I can't find the problem.

Here is a test graph (real have around 150 verticles):

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
v1 = g.addV("person").property(id, 1).property("name", "1").next()
v2 = g.addV("person").property(id, 2).property("name", "2").next()
v3 = g.addV("person").property(id, 3).property("name", "3").next()
v4 = g.addV("person").property(id, 4).property("name", "4").next()
v5 = g.addV("person").property(id, 5).property("name", "5").next()
v6 = g.addV("person").property(id, 6).property("name", "6").next()
g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v2).property(id, 10).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v2).property(id, 11).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v4).property(id, 12).property("weight", 0.2)
g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v6).property(id, 13).property("weight", 1)
g.addE("knows").from(v2).to(v3).property(id, 14).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v3).to(v5).property(id, 15).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v4).to(v5).property(id, 16).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v4).to(v5).property(id, 17).property("weight", 0.3)
g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 18).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 19).property("weight", 0.4)
g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 20).property("weight", 0.2)
```

Comment: Might be an OrientDB-specific issue. The query you've posted should never run into an infinite loop. A minor suggestion though: Don't use `bothE().bothV()` if you later use `simplePath()`. `bothE().bothV()` always produces at least one cyclic path. Also, `not(has(...))` may prevent databases from using internal optimizations, use a negative predicate instead: `g.V(1).repeat(bothE("knows").otherV().hasId(without(2,4,6)).simplePath()).until(hasId(5)).path()`.

Comment: It's really weird. In function of which verticle is filtered, the request will works or not. Is it possible to print a stacktrace to know what he do exactly during the request?

Comment: You could try to do a `profile()` , but if you truly have an infinite loop somehow you will need to find a way to force the traversal to exit. That will mean strategically placing `limit()` steps in your traversal. I'd make given them larger than you would expect numbers, but not so large that the traversal won't complete. Then you can inspect the `profile()` output and see what is taking time where you don't expect it.